# Is the Bower command missing from project?

Tags: bower, azure-web-app-service

I have a deploy.cmd script that I built using these [steps](http://gregtrowbridge.com/deploying-a-bower-dependent-node-app-on-windows-azure/).  It is being used to package a project up for deployment to Azure.  In it there is this line:

```
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bower.json" (
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
call :ExecuteCmd .\node_modules\.bin\bower install
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
popd
```

When I test the script locally, it fails because there is no bower command in the .bin directory.    I have installed bower using -g and have used it to install project packages.  But I can't figure out how it's supposed to make it into this folder.

Comment: Please update your question with some clarifications: 1. how did you get this script? Did you create it yourself or was it generated? 2. Is this an error you see during deployment to an Azure Web App or on your local machine.

Comment: @DavidEbbo  Edited the question and provided a link to source of script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll make it to that folder if you run `npm install bower` without `-g`. `-g` is meant to install tools globally to be available anywhere on your commandline, while not adding `-g` will install it locally in the `node_modules` folder